# Is there a way to determine how to launch any program from the command line

Tags: command-line

Even if there isn't a cli interface. I would like to be able to launch it/ kill it from command line.

Comment: Could you explain exactly what you mean? Do you want to know how to launch programs listed in the applications menu from the command line?

Comment: @DoR any application. I would like to know how to launch and kill it from cli

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Short Version**:

- Find the Exec command for your app by grepping the applications directory

  ```
  grep 'Calculator' /usr/share/applications/*
  ```
- Start the app

  ```
  gcalctool
  ```
- Kill it by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

---

First, find out where your application is. A few directories are in an environment variable `$PATH`, so that you don't have to type the whole directory.

One way to find your app is to open the **Menu Editor** (right click on the Applications Menu and select Edit Menus) and find the app's *command*.

The calculator, for example is `gcalctool` at `/usr/bin/gcalctool` (use the **`whereis`** command to find the exact path of an app). Since `/usr/bin` is in the PATH variable (type `echo $PATH`), you can run it in your terminal by typing `gcalctool`.

It's now running in the foreground. You can pause it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>, resume it in the background by typing `bg`,or resume it in the foreground by typing `fg`. You can also use `fg` to raise an app to the foreground.

If you do this with multiple apps, you can use **`jobs`** to get a numbered list of all of them, and then use, for example, `fg 3` to raise one of them.

An App that is in the foreground can be killed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> (if it doesn't react to the former).

A universal way to find your app is to open the File Browser, go to *Filesystem → usr → share → applications* and to find your app there.

You'll see a bunch of **`.desktop`** files, which you can drag into a Text Editor (or use `cat`) to read. This is a piece of the Calculators .desktop file:
`[Desktop Entry]
Name=Calculator
Comment=Perform arithmetic, scientific or financial calculations
Exec=gcalctool`

The **Exec** entry is what you're interested in here. It's the same you would see if you went to the Menu Editor, just quicker. You can grep the files to search them for your app, if you can't find it.

If the app doesn't have a .desktop file in the applications directory, you have to know it's command of course. Use <kbd>TAB</kbd> to get suggestions from just a few letters. Press <kbd>tab</kbd>, <kbd>tab</kbd>, <kbd>y</kbd> to get a huge list of *every* application.

Comment: Another way is to use the gnome-system-monitor and find the app's logo + matching command line value in the right column.

Answer (score 2):

Even when some applications uses the terminal to monitor the process of a software, there are some other programs that simply run and returns the control to the terminal. So you can close the terminal keeping the application running.

That way, pressing Ctrl-C in the terminal, won't stop the application.

You can use the "killall" command to stop the program when you face that condition in a program.

In example: if you are running kdenlive and it stops responding or you wish (as you say) to close the application using a command in the terminal, just drop a line like:

```
killall kdenlive
```

You can do this with any other application, but if you are running more than one instance of the program which is going to be killed, all the instances of the program are going to be closed.

If you -in example- drop the: killall nautilus in order to close the file browser, you are also closing the main browser that is used for the Desktop management.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
gnome-open <file>
```

Opens any file directly from the command line in its default application.

```
killall <programname>
```

Kills all processes involving