# Accessing main menu

Tags: command-line, menu

I removed my main menu from the Applications menu and want to access it. How can I do this through the command line?  I'm using Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Few clarifications: Are you talking about the Applications menu? Do you want to add it back onto the Panel? (the bar on the top)

Comment: If you want to run the apps you find in the Applications menu from the command line, then this question is probably a duplicate of [Is there a way to determine how to launch any program from the command line](http://askubuntu.com/questions/23272/is-there-a-way-to-determine-how-to-launch-any-program-from-the-command-line/23283#23283)

Comment: http://askubuntu.com/questions/116655/what-is-the-command-to-run-system-settings-from-a-terminal

Answer (score 3):

There's a keyboard shortcut for accessing the main menu, there's no need to use the command line. Just press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>.

Comment: I suppose this do not work if the menu has been removed from the panel.

Comment: It does — I always remove mine from the panel and start it this way.

Comment: Yup it does work, i just tried.

Comment: Doesn't work for example if you use certain other window managers that don’t start whatever `gnome` app runs the main menu.

Answer (score 3):

as @goncalossilva said if you remove Main Menu from panel you can still view it by pressing `ALT+F1`. Alternatively you can install **gnome-main-menu** package using:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-main-menu
```

and then run it from command line or `Alt+F2` using following command:

```
/usr/lib/gnome-main-menu/application-browser
```

If you however want to add Main Menu back to panel just right click on the panel and select **Add to panel...** then in the window that appears select **Menu Bar** or **Main Menu** (which ever you like) and click **Add** button and then click **Close** and you are done.