# What is the command to run System Settings from a terminal?

Tags: command-line

System Settings can be run from the launcher (pinned by default), the Dash, or the power cog. But what command would I enter in a terminal window if I want to run it from there?

Answer (score 310, accepted):

```
gnome-control-center
```

**Note**: for versions between 14.04 and 17.04 (when Unity was used instead of GNOME), the command is `unity-control-center`.

Comment: FYI, on my Ubuntu 14.04 only `gnome-control-center` works.

Comment: @dr01 I assume you are running the Gnome DE and not Unity DE then.

Comment: You can still install the `unity-control-center` on newer versions (17.10+) if you don't like the newer `gnome-control-center`

Comment: Works for me on Ubuntu 18.

Answer (score 31):

if you run `gnome-control-center` and get `command not found`, you can install it with:

```
sudo apt install gnome-control-center
```

Comment: [14.04 and greater may use the command `unity-control-center` instead](http://askubuntu.com/a/116659/18612), which was forked from it. There's no need to install `gnome-control-center` as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Sometimes I cannot find the settings icon anywhere in GNOME, perhaps for my own mistakes. With this command, I got it back.

Answer (score 6):

For [Ubuntu Mate](https://ubuntu-mate.org/) the command is `mate-control-center`.

Answer (score 3):

In Crouton, you must run anything that would require a password from the terminal, such as update manager, software center, synaptic, etc. So, to get to system settings you would enter in the terminal:

```
gnome-control-center
```

That will bring up the system settings GUI.

To check for updates, or if the update manager appears in the Unity Launcher, run it from the terminal, not by clicking on it:

```
sudo update-manager
```

The same applies to synaptic, the software center, etc. Anything which requires a password, must be run from the terminal in Crouton with a `sudo`.

Comment: AFAIK GNOME Control Center does not need `sudo` permissions to run. Also, [using `sudo` to run GUI apps is potentially a bad idea](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/graphicalsudo).

Comment: Yeah well I ran it **without** `sudo` and only three of the setting icons showed up. I ran it **with** `sudo` and **all** the setting icons showed up. What does that tell you?!

Answer (score 3):

I found a different solution...

1. I tried removing/installing `gnome-control-center`; this did reinstall the application I still couldn't open it.
2. Later I found that it would start up on the side of the screen and I couldn't access it
3. I changed the display mode to single display and it came back. Hope it helps.

Comment: Note, you could use `wmctrl` to move it back into the display view area.

Answer (score 3):

Well,
in KDE NEON 5.16.4 (Ubuntu 18.04), it is written in the "System Settings Handbook":

> The System Settings can be started in one of three ways:
>
> - By selecting **Settings → System Settings** from the Application Menu.
> - By pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>. This will bring up the KRunner dialog. Type `systemsettings5`, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
> - Type `systemsettings5 &` at any command prompt. 
>     All three of these methods are equivalent, and produce the same result.

In my case, I needed to configure my HP LaserJet settings. Doing this as user, after applying and saving, they were ignored. So I think I had to do this as root and the settings are stored normaly now, so, each time the user opens the print dialog, the system remembers that I want log side binding and 1200 resolution :=)

I thought that `sudo systemsettings5 &` was enough, but as Zanna suggests: *It should also be recommended to use 'sudo -H' if opening a GUI app with sudo*.

Comment: Why do we need `sudo` here? It seems like a bad idea to unnecessarily run a GUI application as root, especially using plain `sudo` which in most versions of Ubuntu could cause config files in a user's home to become owned by root and (in the worst case scenario) prevent the relevant software from being run by a normal user in future until the ownerships are fixed (which may be confusing for users)

Comment: In my case, I needed to configure my HP LaserJet settings. Doing this as user, after applying and saving, it was ignored. Doing this as root, the settings are stored normaly. Now, each time the user opens the print dialog, it remembers that I want log side binding and 1200 resolution.

Comment: thanks for explaining. I wonder if that behaviour is normal or expected. Some system settings areas prompt me for authorisation, but most do not. I would suggest editing your answer to note that you found you needed to use `sudo` for this purpose for some reason. It should also be recommended to use `sudo -H` if opening a GUI app with `sudo`

Comment: This worked brilliant for me! I had to restore my taskbar and only had the command lind left and so this was essential for me to get back to work! Thank you for sharing this! I didn’t need any sudo though.

Answer (score 3):

**To launch Settings on Ubuntu**

- *gnome desktop* users can use **terminal(Ctrl+t)** or **run command(Alt+F2)**
  to execute :

  ```
  /usr/bin/gnome-control-center
  ```
- For *Cinnamon desktop* users :

  ```
  /usr/bin/cinnamon-settings
  ```
- For *Unity desktop* users :

  ```
  unity-control-center
  ```

Answer (score 0):

One thing no one mentions in this is if you run it from the command line you are likely to encounter errors because some environmental variables aren't being used.

First thing, you shouldn't need sudo to run the control center, but if you do make sure you run it as your user.

```
sudo -i gnome-control-center
```

Also if you run gnome-control-center without sudo it gives permission denied notes.

```
gnome-control-center
/sys/firmware/dmi/tables/smbios_entry_point: Permission denied
/dev/mem: Permission denied
```

So it is useful to know how to run it without running into issues if you are debugging something.

Comment: I don't get (and don't see why I should/could) get any errors running `gnome-control-center` as a regular user. Are you sure is not an issue on your setup or a bug?

Comment: At the time I got some errors and was just sharing the information.  Not even sure this is an issue now.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Cinnamon desktop you can use

```
/usr/bin/cinnamon-settings
```