# xubuntu 14.04 keyboard layout uk gb

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, keyboard-layout

I've just updated my laptop to Xubuntu 14.04, and after the update my keyboard has changed to English-English(US). This is OK for most keys, but it swaps @ with ", and loses the pound sign (The English currency one - not #).

If I go to settings manager > hardware > keyboard, I can change the keyboard to English(UK), but this seems to have no effect.

A new icon appears on the top bar, and this appears now control keyboard layout. Googling has led me to the ibus command and this seems to control this new system. However, the only gb english settings I get from ibus list-engine are:

```
xkb:gb:dvorak:eng - English (UK, Dvorak)
xkb:gb:extd:eng - English (UK, extended WinKeys)
```

The dvorak one completely messes up my alphanumeric keys, the later has the same problems as the US layout.

How do I get back to a bog standard English UK keyboard layout

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer that works for me. I have just found this post: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1284635

That suggests to me ibus is problematic, so I uninstalled it:

```
sudo apt-get remove ibus
```

Then rebooted and everything is back to normal and working properly.

Comment: Very odd bug - and odd, too, that it hasn't been definitively squashed yet. I just experienced it this morning on a vanilla Ubuntu 14.04 setup. I ran the software updater, but can't see [which package would be responsible](https://gist.github.com/dajare/4805e5ce2a8b02c1e725) for messing with this ibus/keyboard setting. I hadn't had any trouble before this morning. As I say - odd! I got back to normal using the [`ibus-setup` workaround](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ibus/+bug/1284635/comments/32) as detailed in that bug-report you helpfully linked to. Thanks!

Comment: Setting the keyboard to English (UK, extended WinKeys) didn't work for me - though it may have been that I didn't delete the English(US) entry.

Comment: I had to follow instructions for reinstalling unity control center after running the command in this post. http://askubuntu.com/questions/116655/what-is-the-command-to-run-system-settings-from-a-terminal

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me after a recent update. To resolve it I went to system settings -> language support ->keyboard input method = none. Logged out and in and it's back to a UK keyboard.