# Kubuntu ibus 14.04 GB (UK) English default keyboard missing

Tags: 14.04, kubuntu, kde, ibus, kde4

I have recently upgraded my machines to Kubuntu 14.04, and it seems that ibus is (partially) broken for selecting the GB (UK) default keyboard.  The closest keyboard that I have to choose from is `English - English (UK, extended WinKeys)` which means that the `back-tick` or `open single quote` key on the left needs to be pressed twice in order to the the character.

Right click (leftmost) icon keyboard with world picture on it:

[image: screenshot of ibus tray icon context menu]

Brings up this menu:

[image: Ibus preferences windows screenshot]

But if I go into:

- System Settings
- Hardware
- Input Devices
- Keyboard
- Layouts
- `Check` Configure layouts
- add, I can configure a GB Default layout.

[image: System Settings - Input Devices - Keyboard]

This article suggest to remove ibus:

[xubuntu 14.04 keyboard layout uk gb](https://askubuntu.com/questions/468155/xubuntu-14-04-keyboard-layout-uk-gb)

Is this solution okay for KDE / Kubuntu?

Comment: FYI I didn't had ibus at my Kubuntu at all. So, probably yes, it is okay. Though I am just now installing it because it have some [useful input methods like the LaTeX.](https://code.google.com/p/ibus/wiki/LaTeX)