# Unity System Settings / Sound app in LXDE

Tags: sound, lxde, system-settings

My preferred set-up is to install Ubuntu and then install the LXDE desktop on top of that.

The one thing I sorely miss from the Unity desktop is the System Settings / Sound app.

Keeping in mind that I have a Ubuntu, not Lubuntu install, just running LXDE desktop, is there a way to run that System Settings / Sound app?

I can run `gnome-control-center` and it opens, but there is no Sound icon in it. I just get a box that looks like this.

[image]

Comment: I guess you need Gnome framework loaded to be able to use various Gnome tools, such as the indicator applet. It would not make very much sense to use lxde if you bring Gnome along. Perhaps you could try Ubutnu Mate or Xubuntu, which do have the sound applet.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm looking for a solution that works on my preferred setup of Ubuntu with LXDE.

Comment: There is now a unity-control-center, you should use this instead of the gnome-control-center. Also, there is a lxpanel-indicator-applet-plugin, have you used this or are you using this?

Comment: @mchid Thanks! `unity-control-center` works! If you care to write that up as an answer, I will be glad to accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with 14.04, Ubuntu introduced the `unity-control-center` to replace the `gnome-control-center`.

You can obtain the classic style controls you desire by installing and using `unity-control-center` instead of `gnome-control-center`

Execute the following commands to install the `unity-control-center`:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install unity-control-center
```

Run the following command to open:

```
unity-control-center &
```

Comment: This is great! And if I give the command `unity-control-center sound` I get just the sound settings, exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Starting with Ubuntu 17.10, it's back to `gnome-control-center` now. `unity-control-center` still exists but is not installed by default, and only shows a few items. See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/116659).

Comment: @tanius I have updated the answer but I think you may be mistaken. I believe that `gnome-control-center` is the one that is missing items. I still use Unity and the `unity-control-center` on 18.04 and the interface is the same as it always has been and was in 14.04 and does not only show a few items.